# How do I make this work using .htaccess - redirect main domain to subdomain & redirect all other pages to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `example.com` which I was able to redirect to `home.example.com`

Using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) https://home.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the other part I'd like to be able to do is to redirect ALL the other URLs to a new domain.

Like `https://example.com/interestingblogpost` to redirect to `https://another.example/interestingblogpost`.

Any advice, I couldn't seem find anything in my searches.

Oh and this is for a WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

Your current directives already redirect ALL URLs to another hostname (a subdomain of the main domain).

If you need to make specific redirects then you simply need to place these *before* your current directives. ie. most specific redirects should be first.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Specific redirects...
RewriteRule ^interestingblogpost$ https://another.example/$0 [R=301,L]

# Redirect everything else to home.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://home.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Assuming this `.htaccess` file only serves `example.com`, then the above would redirect `https://example.com/interestingblogpost` to `https://another.example./interestingblogpost`.

`$0` is a backreference for the entire matched pattern.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing as the earlier 301 that redirects *everything* will likely have been cached (if you had previously requested `/interestingblogpost`). For this reason it is often preferable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects that are not cached by default.